# Kivy - KeyError for ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy

(Do not mark as duplicate, other similar questions do not answer my specific question)

I am attempting to use change screens in my app with a function I defined as `change_screens`. In my kv file, my screen manager has an `id` of `screen_manager`. When I attempt to get the `id` in my python code in the function, I keep getting a `KeyError: 'screen_manager'` error.

**.kv file**

```
<ControlScreens>:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: CardTransition()

    HomeScreen:
        id: home
        name: 'home'
```

**.py file**

```
def change_screen(self, screen_name):

    screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
    screen_manager.current = screen_name
```

Complete Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
            File  "C:/Users/demar/OneDrive/Documents/kivy/Social_Media_App/metropolis.py", l ine  125, in <module>
         MetropolisApp().run()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
         runTouchApp()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
         EventLoop.window.mainloop()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
         self._mainloop()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
         EventLoop.idle()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 340, in idle
         self.dispatch_input()
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
         post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
         listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1360, in on_motion
         self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1376, in on_touch_down
         if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
         return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
         ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
         self.dispatch('on_press')
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
       File "C:\Users\demar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
         exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
       File "C:\Users\demar\OneDrive\Documents\kivy\Social_Media_App\metropolis.kv", line 201, in <module>
         on_press: app.login()
       File "C:/Users/demar/OneDrive/Documents/kivy/Social_Media_App/metropolis.py", line 113, in login
         self.change_screen('logged_in')
           File "C:/Users/demar/OneDrive/Documents/kivy/Social_Media_App/metropolis.py",   line 119, in change_screen
         screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
     KeyError: 'screen_manager'
```

Comment: Please add the complete traceback, as well as the rest of your class.

Comment: @chris my python class?

Comment: Yes, anything someone trying to help you would need to reproduce your issue. Show us exactly what you're doing to get that error.

Comment: Either your `ControlScreen` is beneath another widget, in which case you would have to do `self.root.ids['something'].ids['screen_manager'].current = `. Or perhaps your `ControlScreen` is your root widget, in which case you would just do `self.root.current = `. Try printing out `self.root.ids` as a way to debug things to see what widgets you are actually able to access from `self.root`.

Comment: @Erik My `ControlScreens` is at the top because it holds every other screen. So i'd use `self.root.current = screen_name` correct ?

Comment: That is correct, if `ControlScreen` is indeed your `root` widget. Try just `print(self.root)` and `print(self.root.ids)` somewhere. That's a good way to debug this sort of thing.

Comment: @Erik Thank you so much.

Comment: @Erik Hey Erik, are you free to help with another question?

Comment: @LearningtoCodee if it isn't too long!

Comment: @Erik Lol no promises. If you are able to help I'm greatly appreciative. If not, I understand. It has to do with firebase. Should I make a question or just ask here? It might have an obvious answer

Comment: @LearningtoCodee yeah if it's short enough to write in a comment you can just ask here, otherwise just make a new question about it i guess

Comment: I'll ask in one of my previous questions a few days ago because it is similar to that

Comment: @Erik Not sure if you were able to see it but I tried to tag you